# sitecore session time-out or server failure on publish or browse for package to install

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I am at my wits end on this and can't figure this out.  In sitecore v6.2 something has changed that is causing an error message as follows

"The operation could not be completed.  Your session may have been lost due to a time-out or server failure".

looks like this is coming from Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage?

The request info:

https://sitecore.test.domain.com/sitecore/shell/sitecore/content/Applications/Content%20Editor.aspx?ic=People%2f16x16%2fcubes_blue.png

the response:

{"commands":[{"command":"Alert","value":"The operation could not be completed.\n\nYour session may have been lost\ndue to a time-out or a server failure.\n\nTry again."}]}

At first, I assumed it was because plugged in some new HttpModules so I moved them into the sitecore pipeline model and the problem kept persisting.  I removed them from the entire application and the problem kept persisting.

A google search on the error gets me to some information on the keepalive.aspx stuff, but addressing that has no bearing.

I decompiled the code with reflector, but can't find anywhere this particular error is raised.  It must be in sitecore.nexus or something.

According to my superiors we will open a ticket once we get the build resolved, but here's to hoping someone here has some suggestions.

The constant for this error message is THE_OPERATION_COULD_NOT_BE_COMPLETED_YOUR_SESSION_MAY_HAVE_BEEN_LOSTDUE_TO_A_TIMEOUT_OR_A_SERVER_FAILURE_PLEASE_TRY_AGAIN

Answer (score 0):

This might happened if you server restarts while some dialog opened